# How call function without event handlers in React

Tags: reactjs

I want to change state elements if condition is met. To make this I tried wrote a function where I have this condition and my new state when condition is met. But how can I call this function? I dont need event handlers like onClick or onChange. But how can it be otherwise?

```
this.state = {
    isPresidentVisible: false,
    result: 0,
    minutes: 3,
    seconds: 0,
    isQuizRunning: false,
    isInputDisabled: true,
    isGiveUpVisible: false,
  }
}

  handleChange = (e) => {
    const index = presidents.findIndex(president => (
      president.lastName.toLowerCase() === e.target.value.toLowerCase() || `${president.name.toLowerCase()} ${president.lastName.toLowerCase()}` === e.target.value.toLowerCase()));
    
    if(index !== -1){
      presidents[index].isPresidentVisible = true;
      const isPresidentVisible = presidents[index].isPresidentVisible;
      this.setState(({result}) => ({
        isPresidentVisible,
        result: result + 1
      }))
      e.target.value = '';
    }
  }


  handleClick = () => {
    
    this.setState({
      isQuizRunning: true,
      isInputDisabled: false,
      isGiveUpVisible: true
    })
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      const {seconds, minutes} = this.state
      if(seconds > 0){
      this.setState(({seconds}) => ({
        seconds: seconds - 1
      }))
      }
      if(seconds === 0){
        if(minutes === 0){
          this.handleEndGame();
        } else{
          this.setState(({minutes}) => ({
            minutes: minutes - 1,
            seconds: 59
          }))
        }
      }
    },1000)
  }

  handleEndGame = () => {
    clearInterval(this.interval)
    const isPresidentVisible = presidents.map(president => (president.isPresidentVisible = true))
      this.setState({
        isPresidentVisible,
        isInputDisabled: true,
        isGiveUpVisible: false,
    })
  }
```

I want to make condition:

```
   checkCondition = () => {
    const {result} = this.state;
    if(result === presidents.length){
      this.handleEndGame();
    }
  }
```

Comment: What? What *is* that condition?

Comment: And how can either `result` or `presidents.length` change? Give a [mre], this makes no sense as written.

Comment: where does the variable "presidents" come from?

Comment: @AlekseyPolonka this is imported from other file array with objects inside.

Comment: @ManuLisek I guess you can use checkCondition in componentDidUpdate but from this example, it's hard to tell for sure

Comment: @AlekseyPolonka I tried this but when condition is met i have an error: "Error: Maximum update depth exceeded."

Comment: @ManuLisek of course this is because you need to change your condition after running  this.handleEndGame. Perhaps you can set the result t presidents.length or add one more field to your condition